# Reading input from variable

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am very new to bash scripting and learning on my own.
So, I am writing a simple script to add pass phrase to ssh-agent.

So I do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type your passphrase(followed by ENTER)"
read -s pass
echo ${pass}
ssh-agent bash
```

Now this is where I am confused. 
Next, I want to enter the command ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa that takes the input from read and executes itself.

How do I do that?

So the echo $pass was just to verify if the read was successful. That will be removed and has no meaning here. I just want to simplify the steps of doind this daily:
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
(Asks for pass phrase)

I would like to run this script where it directly asks for passphrase, which will be taken as variabe "pass" & it executes both commands for me.
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Generally, you just let `ssh-add` prompt for and read the necessary passphrase itself. There's no reason to do it yourself.

Comment: Also, `echo $pass` defeats the purpose of using the `-s` flag with `read`.

Comment: Is the goal here a script that can start a bash session under the agent with the key already loaded?